# Изменение значения css при помощи структуры if-else jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if

Мне нужно изменить позицию элемента при нажатии на ссылку. Я нашел один рабочий код, но проблема в том, что он работает через атрибут style

```
var _menu = $(".a-about-me");
var _block = $(".about-me");
_menu.click(function () {
    if (_block[0].style.top === '700px') {
        _block.animate({
            'top': '405px'
        }, 600);
    } else {
        _block.animate({
            'top': '700px'
        }, 600);
    }
});
```

Мне нужно, чтобы менялись значения свойств непосредственно в таблице стилей. Я новенький и не знаю, как исправить... должно быть типа такого

```
var _menu = $(".a-about-me");
var _block = $(".about-me");
_menu.click(function () {
    if (_block[0].css('top') === '700px') {
        _block.animate({
            'top': '405px'
        }, 600);
    } else {
        _block.animate({
            'top': '700px'
        }, 600);
    }
});
```

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _непосредственно в таблице стилей_?

Comment: .css('top') и  .style.top это же одно и то же, стиль в самом файле css изменить невозможно, лишь только внести изменения в дом структуру.

Comment: если убрать `[0]` во втором варианте, то он будет практически эквивалентен первому

Comment: @Grundy  имеется ввиду в файле .css через правила, а не атрибуты тегов

Comment: @Grundy  а можете объяснить, откуда берется и зачем [0] в первом примере? напоминает массив, но откуда тут он...

да, и правда, без него срабатывает) спасибо!

Comment: jQuery возвращает ArrayLike объект - это объект _очень похожий_ на массив. _Изменить_ файл css весьма проблематично, и, в принципе, не нужно. Можно было бы использовать css-классы, **но** `animate` выставляет значение напрямую в тег style, поэтому не стоит ничего выдумывать.

Answer (score 1):

Единственное, что я могу предложить это анимацию через css а в js менять непосредственно классы:

```
.about-me {
     transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     position: absolute;
     top: 405px;
}

.about-me.active {
     top: 700px;
}
```

В js будет следующее:

```
var $menu = $(".a-about-me");
var $block = $(".about-me");
$menu.click(function () {
    $block.toggleClass('active');
    /* or
    if ($block.hasClass('active')) {
        $block.removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $block.addClass('active');
    }
    */
});
```

Это аналог приведенного Вами кода.

Comment: код внутри обработчика может быть заменен на `$block.toggleClass('active')`

Comment: Согласен. В данном случае это лучшее решение